# How to highlight any div with gradient background instead of colour background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Can anyone tell me how to adapt this jQuery's highlight method (see below) to highlight any `div` with **gradient background** instead of pure colour background?

```
$('#myPanel').effect('highlight', {
    color: '#F08F907'
}, 700);
```

or any other ways to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

make a class in css and just use `.addClass()`  method

Answer (score 0):

Try this with pure css

```css
#gradient {
    height: 200px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fe8989, #fedc89); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fe8989, #fedc89); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fe8989, #fedc89); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#fe8989, #fedc89); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}

#gradient1 {
    height: 200px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fe8989, #fedc89, #fe8989); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fe8989, #fedc89, #fe8989); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fe8989, #fedc89, #fe8989); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#fe8989, #fedc89, #fe8989); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

```html
<div id="gradient"></div>
<p></p>
<div id="gradient1"></div>
```

More Detail see the link http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Answer (score 0):

As far as "highlight" is concerned you can only give solid colors. But your requirement can be achieved by following the below code snippet.

JS

```
<div class="target" style="background: #293f50;height: 200px;"></div>
 <button id="button"> Highlight </button>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //do button click
        $("#button").click(function() {
            //setting linear gradient for the div element
            $(".target").css("background", "linear-gradient(to right, #f6f1d3, #648880, #293f50)");

            //highlighting effect 
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                $(".target").fadeTo('slow', 0.5).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
            }
            //setting the normal color after highlighting 
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".target").css("background", "#293f50");
            }, 3500);

        });
    });
</script>
```

Please let me know if this helps

Thanks,